# How to mock subsequent function calls in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, python-unittest, python-mock

I'm new to testing and testing in python. I have a python class that looks like this :

File name : `my_hive.py`

```py
from pyhive import hive

class Hive:
    def __init__(self, hive_ip):
        self.cursor = hive.connect(hive_ip).cursor()

    def execute(self, command):
        self.cursor.execute(command)
```

I want to mock these functions : `pyhive.hive.connect`, `pyhive.Connection.cursor`(used by my class as `hive.connect(hive_ip).cursor()`) and `pyhive.Cursor.execute` (used by my class as `self.cursor.execute(command)` in execute method).

I'm able to mock function call `hive.connect` and also I have been able to assert that it has been called with hive_ip given by me as follows.

```py
import unittest
import mock

from my_hive import Hive

class TestHive(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('pyhive.hive.connect')
    def test_workflow(self, mock_connect):
        hive_ip = "localhost"
        processor = Hive(hive_ip)

        mock_connect.assert_called_with(hive_ip)
```

But how do I make sure that subsequent function calls like `.cursor()` and `self.cursor.execute()` have also been called? `hive.connect(hive_ip)` returns an instance of `pyhive.hive.Connection`, which has method called `cursor`

I have tried to add mocks like this :

```
import unittest
import mock

from hive_schema_processor import HiveSchemaProcessor

class TestHive(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('pyhive.hive.connect')
    @mock.patch('pyhive.hive.Connection.cursor')
    def test_workflow(self, mock_connect, mock_cursor):
        hive_ip = "localhost"
        processor = Hive(hive_ip)

        mock_connect.assert_called_with(hive_ip)
        mock_cursor.assert_called()
```

But the tests are failed with complain :

```
AssertionError: expected call not found.
Expected: cursor('localhost')
Actual: not called.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have already mocked `connect`, so the subsequent calls on the result of `connect` will be made on the mock, not on the real object.
To check that call, you have to make the check on the returned mock object instead:

```py
class TestHive(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('pyhive.hive.connect')
    def test_workflow(self, mock_connect):
        hive_ip = "localhost"
        processor = Hive(hive_ip)

        mock_connect.assert_called_with(hive_ip)
        mock_cursor = mock_connect.return_value.cursor
        mock_cursor.assert_called()
```

Each call on a mock produces another mock object.
`mock_connect.return_value` gives you the mock that is returned by calling `mock_connect`, and `mock_connect.return_value.cursor` contains another mock that will actually be called.